# Overload left shift operator << to object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am not able to overload the left shift operator "<<" so I can use the following code:

```
Foo bar;
bar << 1 << 2 << 3;
```

My class **Foo** looks like this:

```
class Foo{
private:
    vector<int> list;
public:
    Foo();
    void operator<<(int input);
};
```

And the implementation like this:

```
void Foo::operator<<(int input)
{
   // here i want to add the different int values to the vector 
   // the implementation is not the problem
}
```

The code doesn't work I get an error "left operand is of type 'void' ". When I change the return type to **Foo&** it tells me to return something of the type **Foo**. The problem is I can't. I am missing a object reference of the object **bar**.

I searched alot but only found pages who described the operator to output to cout.

Comment: Have you put in the last line of implementation `Foo& operator<<() {... return *this;} `?i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable chaining you must return a reference from the operator. When you write

```
bar << 1 << 2 << 3;
```

That actually is

```
((bar << 1) << 2) << 3;
```

ie `operator<<` is called on the result of `bar << 1` with parameter `2`.

> The problem is I can't. I am missing a object reference of the object bar.

You seem to miss that your `operator<<` is a member function. In `bar`s member functions `*this` is a reference to the `bar` object:

```
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
private:
    std::vector<int> list;
public:
    Foo() {}
    Foo& operator<<(int input);
    void print() const { for (const auto& e : list) std::cout << e << ' ';}
};

Foo& Foo::operator<<(int input)
{
    list.push_back(input);
    return *this;
}

int main() {
    Foo bar;
    bar << 1 << 2 << 3;
    bar.print();
}
```

PS: While constructs such as `bar << 1 << 2 << 3;` can be found in several libraries that predate C++11, nowadays it looks a little old fashioned. You would rather use list initialization or provide a `std::initializer_list<int>` constructor to enable `Foo bar{1,2,3};`.

Comment: Didn't knew about *this. Thank you very much.